# X is dependent on A and B, $P(X|A,B)$ is given along with $P(X|A,!B)$ , how do you find $P(X|A)$

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

In a Bayasian network would look like this,

```
A---,    ____
    |--->|X | 
    |--->|__|    
B --|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DAG is as follows: $$A\lower{2ex}{\searrow\lower{2ex}{X}\swarrow}B$$

Then the factorisation gives: $$\mathsf P(X\mid A)=\mathsf P(X\mid A,B)\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(X\mid A,{!}B)(1-\mathsf P(B))$$